# Is it ok to have multiple models for 1 table

Tags: laravel

When employees log in through

```
site.com/employees/login
```

They get to access the vendor_companies table through

```
App\Models\Employee\VendorCompany Model
```

When vendors log in through

```
site.com/vendors/login
```

They get to access the vendor_companies table through

```
App\Models\Vendor\VendorCompany
```

Is this approach ok?

Comment: Could you explain why you're doing it this way? In most cases, you'd have one model, but use authorization gates to permit different users to do different things within the model.

Comment: @ceejayoz Please refer zedfoxus answer. That is why i am doing this.

Comment: @zaster this was a good question. You have asked other good questions on StackOverflow. Is there a reason you haven't marked more answers as accepted? I'd encourage you to review answers to your questions - this one and other questions - and mark answers that helped you as accepted so other users with similar questions can see a solution you chose.

Comment: @zedfoxus thanks for that tip. I will make sure to update the question as Solved in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although having a single model is most common, what you have is fine. There are times when you want to do customization in one model depending on how you want to treat Vendors. Two different models allow you to have a cleaner separation and makes it easier to maintain functionality, especially between two teams - one team that builds vendor features vs. other team that builds features for employees.

When you build your controllers, you will have to put additional effort to identify whether you are dealing with vendor or employee and then call the appropriate model.

On the flip side, it is common to have a single model and you have customization based on vendor or employee. Give your method a shot and try your methodology.